# vb.net error: inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am working for first time with vb.net code, but I have 5 years experience with C#.

From the previous developer I was told that the code which is on the server runs fine without any errors, but as soon as I opened the website folder (the website doesn't have solution file), I tried to build the site and I got tons of errors saying:

> 'labelControl' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its
>   protection level.

That's happening for all the controls on two of the pages I opened so far.

Here are parts of the markup, logic and designer code for one of the files:

Markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="OverriedCalcValues.aspx.vb" Inherits="Homevesters.Overried_Calc_Values" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">       
    </asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
         <table  cellpadding="5" border="1">                            
         <tr>
                  <td class="style15"><asp:label ID="lblDoorJam1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Door Jamb"/><br />Cost per door jamb replacement</td>
                  <td class="style38"><asp:label ID="lblFactorType1" runat="server"  Text="$/Each"/></td>
                  <td class="style41"><asp:label ID="lblDoorJam" runat="server"  Text=""/></td>
                  <td class="style32"><asp:CheckBox ID="ckDoorJam" runat="server"/></td>
                  <td class="style35">$<asp:TextBox ID="txtDoorJam" runat="server"  Text="" Width="80px" /></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
                  <td class="style16"><asp:label ID="lblExtDoor1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"  Text="Exterior Door"/><br />Cost per exterior door replacement</td>
                  <td class="style39"><asp:label ID="lblFactorType2" runat="server"  Text="$/Each"/></td>
                  <td class="style42"><asp:label ID="lblExtDoor" runat="server"  Text=""/></td>
                  <td class="style33"><asp:CheckBox ID="ckExtDoor" runat="server"/></td>
                  <td class="style36">$<asp:TextBox ID="txtExtDoor" runat="server"  Text="" Width="80px" /></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
                  <td class="style15"><asp:label ID="lblGarageSingle1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Garage (1 Single)"/><br />Cost to replace one single garage door</td>
                  <td class="style38"><asp:label ID="lblFactorType3" runat="server"  Text="$/Each"/></td>
                  <td class="style41"><asp:label ID="lblGarageSingle" runat="server"  Text=""/></td>
                  <td class="style32"><asp:CheckBox ID="ckGarageSingle" runat="server"/></td>
                  <td class="style35">$<asp:TextBox ID="txtGarageSingle" runat="server"  Text="" Width="80px" /></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
                  <td class="style16"><asp:label ID="lblGarageDouble1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"  Text="Garage (1 Double)"/><br />Cost to replace one double garage door</td>
                  <td class="style39"><asp:label ID="lblFactorType4" runat="server"  Text="$/Each"/></td>
                  <td class="style42"><asp:label ID="lblGarageDouble" runat="server"  Text=""/></td>
                  <td class="style33"><asp:CheckBox ID="ckGarageDouble" runat="server"/></td>
                  <td class="style36">$<asp:TextBox ID="txtGarageDouble" runat="server"  Text="" Width="80px" /></td>
         </tr>


         <tr>
                  <td class="style15"><asp:label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Interior Door"/><br />Cost per interior door replacement</td>
                  <td class="style38"><asp:label ID="Label2" runat="server"  Text="$/Each"/></td>
                  <td class="style41"><asp:label ID="lblInteriorDoor" runat="server"  Text=""/></td>
                  <td class="style32"><asp:CheckBox ID="ckInteriorDoor" runat="server"/></td>
                  <td class="style35">$<asp:TextBox ID="txtInteriorDoor" runat="server"  Text="" Width="80px" /></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
                  <td class="style16"><asp:label ID="Label4" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"  Text="Patio Door"/><br />Cost to replace one patio door</td>
                  <td class="style39"><asp:label ID="Label5" runat="server"  Text="$/Each"/></td>
                  <td class="style42"><asp:label ID="lblPatioDoor" runat="server"  Text=""/></td>
                  <td class="style33"><asp:CheckBox ID="ckPatioDoor" runat="server"/></td>
                  <td class="style36">$<asp:TextBox ID="txtPatioDoor" runat="server"  Text="" Width="80px" /></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
                  <td class="style15"><asp:label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Patio Glass"/><br />Cost per patio glass replacement</td>
                  <td class="style38"><asp:label ID="Label6" runat="server"  Text="$/Each"/></td>
                  <td class="style41"><asp:label ID="lblPatioGlass" runat="server"  Text=""/></td>
                  <td class="style32"><asp:CheckBox ID="ckPatioGlass" runat="server"/></td>
                  <td class="style35">$<asp:TextBox ID="txtPatioGlass" runat="server"  Text="" Width="80px" /></td>
         </tr>



                 <tr>        
                  <td class="style16"><asp:label ID="Label7" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Dishwasher"/><br />Cost to replace one dishwasher</td>
                  <td class="style39"><asp:label ID="Label8" runat="server"  Text="$/Each"/></td>
                  <td class="style42"><asp:label ID="lblDishWasher" runat="server"  Text=""/></td>
                  <td class="style33"><asp:CheckBox ID="ckDishwasher" runat="server"/></td>
                  <td class="style36">$<asp:TextBox ID="txtDishwasher" runat="server"  Text="" Width="80px" /></td>
         </tr>                 
</table>                
</asp:Content>
```

Logic:

```
Imports Homevesters

Public Class Overried_Calc_Values
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim clsValueOrganization As New clsCalcValues
    Dim clsValueDefaults As New clsCalcValues


    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If IsUserLoggedIn(Me) = False Then
            Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login.aspx")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If IsPostBack = False Then

            clsValueOrganization.Load("", False, Session("OrgID"))

            clsValueDefaults.Load("", False, "DEFAULT")

            ' c is dollar format with dollar symbol
            lblDoorJam.Text = clsValueDefaults.dDoorJamb.ToString("c")
            lblExtDoor.Text = clsValueDefaults.dExtDoor.ToString("c")
            lblGarageSingle.Text = clsValueDefaults.dGarageDoorSgl.ToString("c")
            lblGarageDouble.Text = clsValueDefaults.dGarageDoorDbl.ToString("c")
            lblInteriorDoor.Text = clsValueDefaults.dIntDoor.ToString("c")
            lblPatioDoor.Text = clsValueDefaults.dPatioDoor.ToString("c")
            lblPatioGlass.Text = clsValueDefaults.dPatioGlass.ToString("c")
            lblDishWasher.Text = clsValueDefaults.dDishwasher.ToString("c")
            lblFans.Text = clsValueDefaults.dFans.ToString("c")
            lblLightFixtures.Text = clsValueDefaults.dLightFixture.ToString("c")
            lblServicePanel.Text = clsValueDefaults.dServicePanel.ToString("c")
            lblRange.Text = clsValueDefaults.dRange.ToString("c")
            lblRefrigerator.Text = clsValueDefaults.dRefrigerator.ToString("c")
            lblStoveTop.Text = clsValueDefaults.dStoveTop.ToString("c")
            lblVentHood.Text = clsValueDefaults.dVentHoods.ToString("c")
            lblElectricalWiring.Text = clsValueDefaults.dWiringReplace.ToString("c")
            lblFloorCovering.Text = clsValueDefaults.dFloorCover.ToString("c")
            lblTileFloor.Text = clsValueDefaults.dTileFloor.ToString("c")
            lblOldHouse4150.Text = clsValueDefaults.dOldHouse1.ToString("c")
            lblOldHouse2140.Text = clsValueDefaults.dOldHouse2.ToString("c")
            lblOldHouse0020.Text = clsValueDefaults.dOldHouse3.ToString("c")
            lblOldHouse1900.Text = clsValueDefaults.dOldHouse4.ToString("c")

            ckMedWood.Checked = Not (clsValueOrganization.dMdWoodWindow = clsValueDefaults.dMdWoodWindow)
            ckSmallMet.Checked = Not (clsValueOrganization.dSmMetalWindow = clsValueDefaults.dSmMetalWindow)
            ckSmallPane.Checked = Not (clsValueOrganization.dSmGlassPanes = clsValueDefaults.dSmGlassPanes)
            ckSmallWood.Checked = Not (clsValueOrganization.dSmWoodWindow = clsValueDefaults.dSmWoodWindow)



        End If



    End Sub



End Class
```

Designer:

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     This code was generated by a tool.
'
'     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
'     the code is regenerated. 
' </auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Strict On
Option Explicit On


Partial Public Class Override_Calc_Values

    '''<summary>
    '''lblDoorJam1 control.
    '''</summary>
    '''<remarks>
    '''Auto-generated field.
    '''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    '''</remarks>
    Protected WithEvents lblDoorJam1 As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label

    '''<summary>
    '''lblFactorType1 control.
    '''</summary>
    '''<remarks>
    '''Auto-generated field.
    '''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    '''</remarks>
    Protected WithEvents lblFactorType1 As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label

    '''<summary>
    '''lblDoorJam control.
    '''</summary>
    '''<remarks>
    '''Auto-generated field.
    '''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    '''</remarks>
    Protected WithEvents lblDoorJam As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label

    '''<summary>
    '''ckDoorJam control.
    '''</summary>
    '''<remarks>
    '''Auto-generated field.
    '''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    '''</remarks>
    Protected WithEvents ckDoorJam As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox

    '''<summary>
    '''txtDoorJam control.
    '''</summary>
    '''<remarks>
    '''Auto-generated field.
    '''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    '''</remarks>
    Protected WithEvents txtDoorJam As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox

    '''<summary>
    '''lblExtDoor1 control.
    '''</summary>
    '''<remarks>
    '''Auto-generated field.
    '''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    '''</remarks>
    Protected WithEvents lblExtDoor1 As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label

    '''<summary>
    '''lblFactorType2 control.
    '''</summary>
    '''<remarks>
    '''Auto-generated field.
    '''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    '''</remarks>
    Protected WithEvents lblFactorType2 As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label

    '''<summary>
    '''lblExtDoor control.
    '''</summary>
    '''<remarks>
    '''Auto-generated field.
    '''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    '''</remarks>
    Protected WithEvents lblExtDoor As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label

    '''<summary>
    '''ckExtDoor control.
    '''</summary>
    '''<remarks>
    '''Auto-generated field.
    '''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    '''</remarks>
    Protected WithEvents ckExtDoor As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox

    '''<summary>
    '''txtExtDoor control.
    '''</summary>
    '''<remarks>
    '''Auto-generated field.
    '''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    '''</remarks>
    Protected WithEvents txtExtDoor As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox

    '''<summary>
    '''lblGarageSingle1 control.
    '''</summary>
    '''<remarks>
    '''Auto-generated field.
    '''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    '''</remarks>
    Protected WithEvents lblGarageSingle1 As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label

    '''<summary>
    '''lblFactorType3 control.
    '''</summary>
    '''<remarks>
    '''Auto-generated field.
    '''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    '''</remarks>
    Protected WithEvents lblFactorType3 As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label

End Class
```

Here are some of the errors I am getting:

[image: Screenshot]

What do you think could be the reason for this?

Comment: did you change the namespace of the code behind file or you changed the Inherits="....." in the page directive of `.aspx` markup. check to see if they match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your code is copied verbatim, then the class name in the Logic block is misspelled and doesn't match the name in the designer file. This causes it to interpreted as two separate classes, which causes the errors. The code in the one file is not able to reference objects defined in the other file. 

Fix the class name in the logic block to match the designer block and the errors should go away.

**Edit**: I noticed it was misspelled in the first line of the markup file as well. Be sure to fix the class name there too.