# Controls not found in designer file or in code file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My designer file has this line in it:

```
Protected WithEvents btnSubmit As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton
```

In my code file, I've got this event handler:

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
```

Which gives me an error saying:

> Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.

**Structure**

On my ASPX page, I'm inheriting `SmartpeepsMobi.Personalize`:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Members/Members.Master" CodeBehind="Personalize.aspx.vb" Inherits="SmartpeepsMobi.Personalize" %>
```

In my code file, I've put the partial class for the page into a namespace called SmartpeepsMobi:

```
Namespace SmartpeepsMobi

    Public Class Personalize
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    End Class
End Namespace
```

I've also put the stuff in the designer file into the same Namespace:

```
Namespace SmartpeepsMobi

    Partial Public Class Personalize

    End Class

End Namepsace
```

This code is copied verbatim.
Despite this structure, I'm getting a lot of errors on ONLY this page:

> 'txtWeight' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
>   Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.
>   'txtWeight' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
>   'txtWeight' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
>   'lblmsg' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
>   'lblmsg' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
>   'lnkCancel' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
>   'lblmsg' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
>   'lblmsg' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
>   'lblmsg' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
>   'lblmsg' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

All of these controls are present in the designer file and in the .aspx page.

I've tried building the project without the files open as per the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937998/var-nameis-not-declared-it-may-be-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level).
I added the namespace and checked the inheritance and references as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483579/vb-net-error-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level).

I'm pretty lost here and I feel like I'm out of things to try. Does anyone have any suggestions on a fix?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Last night when I asked about this on IRC, the whole channel started making fun of me for some reason in relation to the fact that I don't use source control... mostly because I don't understand how to use any of them really

Comment: could you put the download link  of your code?

Comment: Unfortunately, as this code is for a commercial application being sold by my client, I could probably face lawsuits if I did that

Comment: @AngusChung however as its only partial code, here's a screenshot for you http://i.imgur.com/8jIJFUm.png

Comment: OK. could you put a screenshot of masterpage?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/k5bbvsz.png

Comment: Could you put screenshot of Personalize.vb and Personalize.designer.vb include "Namespace SmartpeepsMobi"?

Comment: @AngusChung thanks for your attention so far, but I'm not seeing where this is going... Can you explain a bit about what you're looking for?

Comment: It's ok, i mean that i want the screenshot include these word "Namespace SmartpeepsMobi".

Comment: Seriously? I think I know enough to get that much right but as you're the only one anywhere (I'm asking friends on skype, reddit, irc as well) that's trying to help, here you go: http://i.imgur.com/uLuMV56.png

Comment: It's really ok. But i still can not simulate the same situation according to these information you provided. Are there any other class name equal "Personalize"?

Comment: Have you ever try to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: Rebuild is where the problem occurs

Comment: we can talk about it in chat.